# Create an XML file from a script AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I can not figure out how I get more XML file from the language images,

[In the image here you will look at setupItems how it is built](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LoqK.png)

[Here it explains how I build the missing XML file but I do not understand how I build it properly that will work for me on the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2yog.png)

```
public function init(param1:int) : void
  {
     var _loc2_:String = null;
     this.itemHolder.addChild(this.hairHolder);
     this.itemHolder.addChild(this.shirtHolder);
     this.shirtHolder.visible = false;
     this.itemHolder.addChild(this.pantsHolder);
     this.pantsHolder.visible = false;
     this.itemHolder.addChild(this.shoesHolder);
     this.shoesHolder.visible = false;
     this.activeHolder = this.hairHolder;
     this.initButtons();
     this.randomTimer = new Timer(this.randomTimerInitDelay,this.randomTimerCount);
     this.randomTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,this.changeRandomClothes,false,0,true);
     this.xml = new XML();
     if(param1 == 1)
     {
        _loc2_ = "boyItems.xml";
     }
     else if(param1 == 2)
     {
        _loc2_ = "girlItems.xml";
     }
     this.xmlLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("./website/common/register/xmls/" + _loc2_));
     this.xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,this.xmlLoaded);
     this.xmlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,this.errorLoadingXml);
  }
```

another code

```
private function xmlLoaded(param1:Event) : void
  {
     this.xmlLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,this.xmlLoaded);
     this.xmlLoader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,this.errorLoadingXml);
     this.xml = XML(this.xmlLoader.data);
     Register.AVATAR_HAIR = this.xml.hair.child(0).@id;
     var _loc2_:int = Math.random() * 2 + 1;
     this.bubble.gotoAndStop("hair_" + Register.language + _loc2_);
     this.setupItems(this.xml.hair,this.hairItems,this.hairHolder);
     this.setupItems(this.xml.shirt,this.shirtItems,this.shirtHolder);
     this.setupItems(this.xml.pants,this.pantsItems,this.pantsHolder);
     this.setupItems(this.xml.shoes,this.shoesItems,this.shoesHolder);}

  
  private function setupItems(param1:*, param2:Array, param3:Sprite) : void
  {
     var _loc9_:* = undefined;
     var _loc10_:Item = null;
     var _loc4_:int = 54.5;
     var _loc5_:Number = 64.5;
     var _loc6_:*;
     var _loc7_:int = (_loc6_ = param1).children().length();
     var _loc8_:int = 0;
     while(_loc8_ < _loc7_)
     {
        _loc9_ = _loc6_.child(_loc8_);
        (_loc10_ = new Item()).x = _loc4_;
        _loc4_ += this.itemSpacing;
        _loc10_.y = _loc5_;
        _loc10_.loadItem(_loc9_.@type,_loc9_.@ordinal,_loc9_.@id,_loc9_.@inventoryType,Register.pathToItemsFolder);
        param2.push(_loc10_);
        param3.addChild(_loc10_);
        _loc8_++;
     }
  }
```

This is the **loadItem** file: 
(Maybe here you can see how I build the XML files)

```
public function loadItem(param1:int, param2:int, param3:int, param4:int, param5:String) : void
  {
     this.type = param1;
     this.ordinal = param2;
     this.id = param3;
     this.itemImage = new ImageItemNoCache(param1,param2,param3,param4,null,null,param5);
     this.itemImage.mouseEnabled = false;
     this.itemImage.mouseChildren = false;
     this.itemImage.addEventListener(ImageItem.DATA_LOADED,this.positionImage,false,0,true);
     addChild(this.itemImage);
     addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,this.clickedMe,false,0,true);
  }
```

Code for **ImageItemNoCache**:

```
public class ImageItemNoCache extends ImageItem
{
    private var textData:Object;

    private var itemData:Object;

    private var pathToItemsFolder:String;

    public function ImageItemNoCache(param1:int, param2:int, param3:int, param4:int, param5:Object = null, param6:Object = null, param7:String = ".")
    {
        this.textData = param5;
        this.itemData = param6;
        this.pathToItemsFolder = param7;
        super(param1,param2,param3,param4);
    }

    override protected function getImageItemData(param1:int, param2:int = -1, param3:int = -1, param4:int = -1) : ImageItemData
    {
        return new ImageItemDataNoCache(param1,param2,param3,param4,this.textData,this.itemData,this.pathToItemsFolder);
    }

    override public function clone() : DisplayItem
    {
        return new ImageItemNoCache(getType(),getOrdinal(),getId(),getInventoryType(),this.textData,this.itemData,this.pathToItemsFolder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your as code blocks, not screen captures (Someone can try to execute it)

Comment: Hi, i added the codes

Comment: What is the **exact** problem? What is the purpose of creating an XML? An XML is just [a text file](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_whatis.asp). Either you want to add extra entries into an existing XML text file (use Notepad) or you want to read extra entries from existing XML file (use AS3 to read those XML nodes)? Did you try making an XML in a text tool (like Notepad) then load that XML into AS3?

Comment: I know how to create an xml file, but I do not know what values ​​inside should be according to the codes I sent above how the file should be arranged

Comment: There are codes to fill two xml files one boyItems.xml and the other girlItem.xml now I created both but I do not know what values ​​should be inside

Comment: Unless your function `loadItem()` shows (maybe in some `IF` statement) the entry names of items like **id** and **inventoryType** then you cannot recreate. You need the original XML files to check possible entries. Get them from same place you got the SWF from. Maybe the SWF itself has clues. Did you open it in Animate and check the **Library** for anything useful?

Comment: I can not get the original XML files I just try to recreate them

Comment: For example in the XML you can see that there is entry called **type** (the `@type` entry) so maybe check if the SWF has something like "Hair" (either as a Class or a MovieClip object, etc). You can assume **type** will be either a Number or a String. Check if `loadItem()` has an **IF** like: `if( type == 2 ) { /* do someThing */ }` at least this way, now you know "type" is a Number. Or else check what the function does with "type" value, like does it access some other MC's frame (eg: `gotoAndStop()`) or does it access / load / add some Graphic or Class?

Comment: OK,
I need to create two files one boyitems.xml and girlitems.xml

Look I added the loadItem code

Comment: See if you have a Class or MovieClip called `ImageItemNoCache` (maybe is a file called **ImageItemNoCache.as** or is shown somewhere in **Library**). That function should have the `IF` statements that you can use to know what Numbers are expected from the XML.

Comment: hi, look the code up

Comment: Ok. You can see the Class `ImageItemNoCache` is **extending** a Parent Class called `ImageItem` so that line `super(param1,param2,param3,param4);` must be talking to some **imageItem.as** (or MovieClip, because they too can act like class, with code embedded inside the MC Object)... Anyways you can see your expected values are Numbers. You can either experiment for which numbers work or check **imageItem.as** for possible clues.

Comment: PS: What happens, in your own XML, if you use `1` for the Ints and `"test"` for the String?

Comment: I was able to fix this by adding two xml files <data> </data> and adding the correct codes, and also forgot to add xml version = 1.0 encoding = utf-8 to the xml files

Comment: Glad it's sorted. PS: You say you added two XML files? But then you show two **nodes** (of `<data>` and `</data>`). So when you asked _"How to get more files?"_ did you actually mean _"How to get more <nodes>"_?

Comment: Thanks, for the two xml files I added <data> <\ data> at the beginning and at the end I succeeded